# ¿Como agrego una imagen de fondo a mi scene en JavaFx?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-css

```
package application;

import java.awt.Image;

import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundPosition;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundRepeat;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundSize;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class voto {
    public static boolean display(String string, String string2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        HBox hb4 = new HBox();

        Stage window = new Stage();
        window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        window.setTitle("Detalles");
        window.setMinWidth(250);








        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(hb4);
        vBox.setPadding(new Insets(5,250,100,5));
        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.showAndWait();
        //retotna repsuesta para hacer
        return true;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

podrias hacer estas dos opciones:

Crear un archivo "style.css"  y define el ID

```html
#pane{
    -fx-background-image: url("background_image.jpg");
    -fx-background-repeat: stretch;   
    -fx-background-size: 900 506;
    -fx-background-position: center center;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, black, 30, 0.5, 0, 0); 
}
```

2) Establecer el id del control más alto (o cualquier control) en la escena con el valor definido en CSS y cargar este archivo CSS en la escena:

```html
public class Test extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.setId("pane");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        scene.getStylesheets().addAll(this.getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

```html
<StackPane id="pane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="demo.Sample">
    <children>
    </children>
</StackPane>
```

También puede dar un id al control en un archivo FXML:

Para obtener más información acerca de JavaFX CSS Styling, consulte esta [guia](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html).

la segunda opcion :

n caso de que desee hacerlo de forma programática o la forma java

Para Fondos de Imagen; Puede utilizar la clase [BackgroundImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BackgroundImage.html) class

Para pintar o rellenar fondos; Puede utilizar la clase  [BackgroundFill](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BackgroundFill.html)
 class

```html
BackgroundFill myBF = new BackgroundFill(Color.BLUEVIOLET, new CornerRadii(1),
         new Insets(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0));// or null for the padding
//then you set to your node or container or layout
myContainer.setBackground(new Background(myBF));
```

Mantiene tu java vivo && tu css muerto.
[Fuente de la respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738146/javafx-how-to-set-scene-background-image)

Answer (score 0):

Una forma sencilla de añadir una imagen de fondo, programaticamente a la ventana, es añadiendo un ***ImageView*** al contenedor:

```
package javafx_imagen_fondo;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXImagenFondo extends Application {
    private final Image bgImage = new Image("file:src/javafx_imagen_fondo/fondo.jpg");
    private final StackPane container = new StackPane();
    private final Scene scene = new Scene(container);
    private final Text label  = new Text("Hello word");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        // Asigna un titulo y dimensiones al "stage"
        primaryStage.setTitle("Prueba imagen de fondo");
        primaryStage.setMinHeight(240);
        primaryStage.setMinWidth(320);

        // Añado imagen de fondo a la ventana
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
        imageView.setImage(bgImage);
        imageView.setFitHeight(240);
        imageView.setFitWidth(320);
        container.getChildren().add(imageView);

        // Añado algo de texto a la ventana (la imagen estará primero)
        label.setFill(Color.RED);
        label.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.BOLD, 38));
        container.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        container.getChildren().add(label);

        // Mostrar ventana
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

} // class
```

El código anterior genera una ventana como la siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La imagen es un *fondo negro con una espiral dibujada*. Fijate en la ruta, va precedida por "file:" y situó la imagen junto con la clase. Seguramente querrás tener un directorio propio donde almacenar las imágenes, entonces la ruta podría ser una como por ejemplo la siguiente:

```
Image bgImage = new Image("file:src/resources/imagenes/fondo.jpg");
```

Esta es una forma bastante "limpia" de añadir una imagen de fondo, si lo hacemos en el propio código, pero hay que tener en cuenta dos cosas:

1. Añadir el *ImageView* en primer lugar al elemento contenedor, es decir, antes que los textos, botones y otros elementos, para que estos aparezcan sobre esta "imagen de fondo". Si se añadieran antes la imagen los ocultaría.
2. Para que la imagen efectivamente aparezca como un fondo, le damos las mismas dimensiones que a la ventana, habrá que tener en cuenta la resolución de esta y que si la ventana se redimensiona agrandándola, la imagen ya no ocupará todo el área visible, es decir no aumenta desde el tamaño asignado. Podemos bloquear el redimensionado de la pantalla con la instrucción: `primaryStage.setResizable(false);`
   Si no "bloqueamos el redimensionado", reducir la pantalla no es tan crítico, se reduce hasta el tamaño real de la imagen, es decir que si la imagen que use tuviera por ejemplo un tamaño de 300x200 px la ventana solo se puede reducir hasta que alcanza este tamaño, otra cosa es cómo afecta esto al posicionamiento de los diferentes elementos. Yo prefiero fijar el tamaño.